# Manage multiple many-to-one relationships with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm dealing with the development of a **JPA Data Access Layer** by using **Hibernate** as **ORM**.

I should manage a relation schema as shown below:

[image]

**Hibernate** generated the following entities:

- `UserAccount`
- `Workgroup`
- `WorkgroupPrivilege`
- `UserAccountHasWorkgroup`
- `UserAccountHasWorkgroupId` (`EmbeddedId`)

The code is available as **Github Gist**: **https://gist.github.com/vdenotaris/5b50188fe11b6e5439d8**

Now, I'm trying to add a member (an `UserAccount`) to a `Workgroup` as follows:

```
public void addMembership(final Long workgroupId,
        final UserAccount newMember,
        final WorkgroupPrivilege workgroupPrivilege,
        final UserAccount approvedBy) {
    Workgroup workgroup = super.findById(workgroupId);
    Set<UserAccountHasWorkgroup> memberships = workgroup.getUserAccountHasWorkgroups();
    System.out.println("Memberhsips: <" + memberships.size() + ">");
    UserAccountHasWorkgroup membership = new UserAccountHasWorkgroup();
    UserAccountHasWorkgroupId id = new UserAccountHasWorkgroupId();
    id.setUserAccountId(newMember.getId());
    id.setWorkgroupId(workgroupId);
    membership.setId(id);
    membership.setWorkgroupPrivilege(workgroupPrivilege);
    membership.setUserAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId(approvedBy);
    memberships.add(membership);
    workgroup.setUserAccountHasWorkgroups(memberships);
    jpaEntityManager().update(workgroup);
}
```

But it returns me the following error:

```
17:02:18,235 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component WorkgroupDAO for method public void it.prisma.dal.dao.accounting.WorkgroupDAO.addMembership(java.lang.Long,it.prisma.dal.entities.accounting.UserAccount,it.prisma.dal.entities.accounting.WorkgroupPrivilege,it.prisma.dal.entities.accounting.UserAccount): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find it.prisma.dal.entities.accounting.UserAccountHasWorkgroup with id it.prisma.dal.entities.accounting.UserAccountHasWorkgroupId@513a85eb
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at it.prisma.dal.dao.accounting.WorkgroupDAO$$$view7.addMembership(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried persisting the membership object and then updating the memberships set?